# Cannot compile due to errors in R.java build file

Tags: java, android, layout

I am learning Java and trying to make a basic Android application with Android Studio. When I try to add a TableLayout to an XML page the project will no longer compile because of errors in R.java.

Here are the errors:

Error: identifier expected

Error: illegal start of type

Error: identifier expected

These errors are repeated three times. Here are the lines it occurs on in R.java:

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int 1=0x7f0b0086;
    public static final int 2=0x7f0b0087;
    public static final int 3=0x7f0b0088;
```

I'm guessing it fails because 1, 2, and 3 are not valid variable names, but I cannot change anything about a Java build file.

I found that others with similar problems in R.java were able to solve it by cleaning and rebuilding the solution, but this did not work for me. It will compile during the clean, but will fail to compile if I try to run it after that.

Comment: I already face this problem some time and got this error. I'm pretty sure you are falling in same issue. check my answere, hope you can handle this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that at some XML (like layout/*.xml) you have tags with ids with those names `android:id="@+id/1"`

Since numbers are not a valid java identifier you must change the values in the XML to a alphanumeric string such 'a' ...

The class R is a compilation of the identifiers from all resources into `res` their names will be a variable into R, so name accordlyng

Answer (score 0):

I got this error for wrong nameing:

```
<string name="1ab">text</string>
```

Resource name must begin with character and it worked

```
<string name="ab">text</string>
```

So just check if you have any resource name with wrong character in all your resource file(**string.xml, style.xml, attrs.xml**) and folder(**drawable, layout**).

> **Note:** A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length
>   sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the
>   dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "_".

Thank you.